# Angular Cli - SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: angular, typescript, code-coverage, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I am trying to generate coverage report with angular cli. however I keep getting following error. I am not quite sure if This is cli error or problem with my Karma.conf? `ng test` /`npm test` Runs fine... So something to do with code-coverage option?

```
    Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (3:0)
        at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4443:13)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1875:16)
        at Parser.parseStatement (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:5795:22)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2262:21)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1772:8)
        at Parser.parse (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1667:17)
        at Object.parse (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:7163:37)
        at Instrumenter.instrumentSync (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\istanbul-lib-instrument\dist\instrumenter.js:121:31)
        at Instrumenter.instrument (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\istanbul-lib-instrument\dist\instrumenter.js:176:32)
        at Object.module.exports (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\istanbul-instrumenter-loader\index.js:25:25),Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import
    ' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (2:0)
        at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4443:13)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1875:16)
        at Parser.parseStatement (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:5795:22)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2262:21)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1772:8)
        at Parser.parse (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1667:17)
        at Object.parse (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:7163:37)
        at Instrumenter.instrumentSync (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\istanbul-lib-instrument\dist\instrumenter.js:121:31)
        at Instrumenter.instrument (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\istanbul-lib-instrument\dist\instrumenter.js:176:32)
        at Object.module.exports (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\istanbul-instrumenter-loader\index.js:25:25)
        at Compiler.compiler.plugin (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\@angular\cli\plugins\karma-webpack-throw-error.js:10:23)
        at Compiler.applyPlugins (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:61:14)
        at Watching._done (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:91:17)
        at onCompiled (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:50:17)
        at C:\Development\source\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:480:13
        at next (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:138:11)
        at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\webpack\lib\CachePlugin.js:62:5)
        at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:142:13)
        at C:\Development\source\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:477:10
        at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
        at self.applyPluginsAsync.err (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:640:19)
        at next (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:138:11)
        at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:122:5)
        at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:142:13)
        at self.applyPluginsAsync.err (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:631:11)
        at next (C:\Development\source\\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:138:11)
```

My karma.conf looks like this

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'json'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
      ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
      : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same issue today, the fix in my case was a change to the tsconfig.spec.json file. I changed the module entry from `"module": "es2015"`
to `"module": "commonjs"`

This resolved the compilation error running `ng test --cc` and created the expected coverage report. Hope this helps!